# How to write down each month borrowing over past month

Tags: loans, debt, family, record-keeping

Since Pandemic I had lost my job and borrowed money or money sent by my parents from saving but I couldn't write it down as I am financially illiterate/bad with maths. Now and in past, it has caused me a lot of stress in my life.

The only way I see it is to write down via tallying from my banking app and from reference but how do I write it down e.g. My money vs borrowed money vs gifted money and find out how much I borrowed and got gifted so when the time comes, I can return the favor.

I realized that most of the problem is not being able to write down each item but writing down each dollar/pound seems a huge task.

How do I solved this problem and make it a habit so I can teach my children as well

Comment: what tools do you have access to? Do you have a computer with Excel or equivalent? Can you access Google Sheets from a device of your own? Or are you looking for a pen-and-paper technique?

Comment: @KateGregory Everything but I prefer pen-and-paper

Comment: @localhost pen and paper in a notebook will work just fine.  Only remember to be organized: dates all lined up, names/descriptions lined up, amounts lined up.

Comment: There are also many finance apps - they are less flexible than a spreadsheet in what you can report and enter - but in this case might be better as they enforce entering the same information for each entry. Unfortunately to see if they work you have to use them, try a trial version

Answer (score 14):

Make a spreadsheet. On your own device, a Google Sheet or any other reputable cloud service provider.

Make columns that each say someone's name and "gift" or "loan".

Eg "Mum loan", "Mum gift", "J loan", "J gift" and so on across the sheet.
Make a column before all of those for the date.

Now enter a row for any time someone gave money to you or provided a loan. Eg:

```
           Mum loan    Mum gift
Sept 5th       900         100
```

(This if your mum provided you 1000 and told you 100 of it was a gift and to pay the rest back when you can.)

Go back and add entries for the past as best as you can remember.

Now you can total the whole column to see what someone has lent or given you, or total some ranges to see how much you needed in a particular month. You could do some clever formatting where you used a different colour for different months to let you see what's going on.

Examples:

[image: Excel totalling a column]

Here the Mum loan column is all selected. Down in the status bar Excel shows the total of that column.

[image: Excel totalling a rectangle]

Here all the February entries are selected. Again the total (sum) is in the status bar.

Should you be able to pay someone back, use a negative entry:

```
           Mum loan    Mum gift
Sept 5th       900         100
Sept 6th      -100
```

You might want to add another column with a reason or description -- did someone pay a bill for you, hand you cash, deposit into your bank account? Did you repay them in cash or with an e-transfer? These might be helpful if family's patience ends up wearing thin and there are arguments about who sent what to whom and when.

Once a transaction is recorded, it may well weigh on you less. Not keeping all this in your head should reduce your stresss.

Comment: Exactly.  Addition and subtraction are all you need.  Heck, paper and pencil in a notebook, or the grid feature of your smartphone’s Note app.

Comment: the nice thing about the spreadsheet is the ease of totalling different ranges as you want to know them.

Comment: Kate, absolutely spreadsheets are wonderful.  With just addition and cell linking between tabs, one keeps track of all my spending.  My point, though, was that a spreadsheet **is not mandatory** just to do what OP wants.  Many years ago, at a low point in my life, I needed to borrow money to survive.  **Pencil and paper** is how I recorded it.

Comment: Great explanation, however I would say that whether having the spreadsheet on your own device or in the cloud is more secure is dependent on many factors: strength of cloud service password, physical and information security of your device, etc.

Comment: thank you for the breakdown, I want to add who paid for x bill for y month. I looked at my diary from before when I tried to write down expenses and it is so horrible like it is everywhere.. As for spreadsheets, I do not know how to use formulas or any stuff except writing in cell and colouring it.

Comment: That's all you need to do. If someone paid a bill for you, add a line for the day they did it, fill in the date, description (eg paid my phone bill) and then in the column for their name either gift or loan, write the amount of the bill.  You don't need any formulas.

Comment: *"On your own device is more secure than a Google Sheet or other cloud thing."* More secure in terms of privacy: sure. More secure in terms of backup: Definitely not. To be honest, in this case I would recommend the opposite, and advise OP to use cloud storage. We all know that end-users don't make backups, so the risk of data loss is high. On the other hand, the risk of someone being interested in OP's debts *and being able to do something malicious with it* is very low. Apart from that, great advice!

Comment: @localhost "As for spreadsheets, I do not know how to use formulas or any stuff except writing in cell and colouring it" — if you use [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets), you can just click in the column letter and it will highlight the whole column — down in the bottom right hand corner, it will tell you what the column sums up to without needing any formulas or anything

Comment: @anotherdave Excel does the same.

Comment: @KateGregory Ah cool, I couldn't remember for sure and don't have it installed so didn't want to promise it if missing :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your innumeracy is making you overthink this.

```
Date             Amount
-----------------------
2020-12-01        $1,000
2021-01-01        $1,000
2021-02-01        $1,200
```

etc.

The biggest problem is not misplacing the sheet of paper you record this on. I'd recommend taping it to the inside of your bedroom or a closet door, so it's not out in the open for any guests to see.

You can keep separate lists for loans and for gifts. Once you are more comfortable with doing *some* amount of record keeping, you can make the leap to combining the two into one list, with separate tags for loans and gifts:

```
Date         Type          Amount
---------------------------------
2020-12-01     Loan         $1,000
2020-12-25     Gift            200
2021-01-01     Loan          1,000
2021-02-01     Loan          1,200
```